# How to filter audio files according to tacts per minute (speed)?

Tags: command-line, sound, bash, python, tools

I have some music collection and I want to sort/filter them easily according to their speed (in tacts per minute). I want to find a simple solution to filter the whole collection using e.g bash, python, existing simple tool, etc. Do you know any solution?

Comment: Filter it where? in a music player? In a folder? view it in a terminal

Comment: I have about 500 audio files and I want to filter/sort them anywhere and anyhow. I imagine there is some little library or script for terminal, where I could just set folder, and I'll get a list of files and their speeds (could be sorted as well, but regex could do too). But any solution like filtering them in some audio player or so would be enough too.

Comment: Calculating the tempo in BPM is a major feat in digital signal processing, although I suppose for some dance music with a strong beat and a constant tempo it wouldn't be so hard. But a simple solution, no.